# Mongoose Object Array won't work on Postman

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, postman

After completing a course on MEAN Stack, I'm working on making my own webapp - a recipe page. I've designed my models, but when I try to fill the database with a new Recipe it just won't work. The main issue is the way I want to store ingredients, they'll be stored on one of the tables, then each recipe has its list of ingredients and amounts for each. For example, to make some toast you need, say "50 grs. of Butter and 4 slices of Bread". This is the Schema I'm using:

```
var RecipeSchema = Schema({
    name: String,
    desc: String,
    author: { type: Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'User' },
    category: { type: Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'Category' },
    ingredients: [{ amount: String, ingredient: { type: Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'Ingredient' }}],
    steps: [String],
    image: String,
    thumbnail: String,
    portions: Number,
    difficulty: Number,
    cookingTime: Number,
    comment: String
});
```

When I go in Postman and try to fill the "Toast Recipe" entry, I have the following:

```
name:Toast
desc:Toast is a common breakfast staple.
author:5cad791a7b2e651f7803f5de
category:5cb1ff8f484a172984178a97
ingredients:[{"amount": "4 slices", "ingredient": "5cb1ffdb484a172984178a98"}, {"amount": "35 grs.", "ingredient": "5cb2000d484a172984178a99"}]
steps:['Toast the bread in the oven.','Spread some butter on each toast.']
image:'null'
thumbnail:'null'
portions:1
difficulty:1
cookingTime:15
comment:'null'
```

But I keep getting a "cast Array" error. What could be the issue? Is it a problem with my model, with Postman, or with the way I'm sending the Array?

**EDIT:**

Apparently it was a problem whit the way I posted my arrays in Postman. After some more tests I managed to upload a full recipe in JSON format. The structure is correct (but what Juan suggests can be used too, to make the code cleaner).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'am not completely sure, but when I worked with mongoose, inner objects had a new Schema object inside, in this case it would on ingredients

```
const IngredientSchema = new Schema({ 
    amount: String, 
    ingredient: { type: Schema.ObjectId, ref:'Ingredient' }
});

const RecipeSchema = new Schema({
    name: String,
    desc: String,
    author: { type: Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'User' },
    category: { type: Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'Category' },
    ingredients: [ IngredientSchema ],
    steps: [String],
    image: String,
    thumbnail: String,
    portions: Number,
    difficulty: Number,
    cookingTime: Number,
    comment: String
});
```